# How to create a set rows for every group depending on the result after the operation in the groupby() Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation where my pandas dataframe **df** looks like below:

```
        stay_id       starttime       charttime           dd            day delta total cum_uo
     0  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 13:00:00 0 days 11:30:00  0   0     0   90.0   
     1  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 14:00:00 0 days 10:30:00  0   1     1   215.0
     2  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 15:00:00 0 days 09:30:00  0   1     2   325.0
     3  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 16:00:00 0 days 08:30:00  0   1     3   370.0
     4  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 17:00:00 0 days 07:30:00  0   1     4   425.0
     5  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 18:00:00 0 days 06:30:00  0   1     5   490.0
     6  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 19:00:00 0 days 05:30:00  0   1     6   540.0 
     7  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 20:00:00 0 days 04:30:00  0   1     7   615.0
     8  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 21:00:00 0 days 03:30:00  0   1     8   660.0
     9  30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 22:00:00 0 days 02:30:00  0   1     9   710.0
     10 30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 23:00:00 0 days 01:30:00  0   1     10  740.0
     11 30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-14 00:00:00 0 days 00:30:00  0   1     11  780.0
     12 30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-14 01:00:00 -1 days+23:30:00 -1  1     12  905.0
     13 30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-14 02:00:00 -1 days+22:30:00 -1  1     13  1255.0
```

The frame I am showing above is `grouped by stay_id, starttime`.

I want to add  `the hour from "total" column` as a **new column** for `minimum value of delta=0 days 00:30:00`, for `df["day"]==0"`.

**What I tried**:

```
def helper(rows):
   val = rows[rows["day"]==0]["dd"].min()
   d_hour_array =rows[rows["dd"]==val]["total"].values[0]
   return d_hour_array

df.groupby(['stay_id', 'starttime']).apply(helper)
```

**The result I am getting**

```
stay_id      starttime  
    
30578301  2154-03-14 00:30:00    11
          2154-03-14 05:11:00    16
          2154-03-14 09:41:00    20
          2154-03-14 19:05:00    29
          2154-03-15 09:59:00    44
          2154-03-15 20:58:00    55
dtype: int64
```

**How to add the values as new column `11, 16, 20, 29, 44, 45` from the result to each group after `groupby(['stay_id', 'starttime'])?**

(like creating **df["d_hour"]** for each group).

**Expected Output:**

```
        stay_id       starttime       charttime           dd            day delta total cum_uo d_hour
        30578301 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 13:00:00 0 days 11:30:00  0   0     0   90.0   11
                 2154-03-14 00:30:00 2154-03-13 14:00:00 0 days 10:30:00  0   1     1   215.0  11
        30578301 2154-03-14 05:11:00 2154-03-13 14:00:00 0 days 13:11:00 0    1     3   370.0  16
                 2154-03-14 05:11:00 2154-03-13 17:00:00 0 days 12:11:00 0    1     4   425.0  16
```

Any help is much appreciated please...

Comment: Hi Priya, it's not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example with the expected output? :)

Comment: I have edit my question..basically the issue is to add `d_hour` column for every group of rows that get generated after grouping (stay_id, starttime)

Comment: there are still some inconsistencies. There's 2 "delta" in the columns, and on the code you get "total_t" which is not in your initial dataframe. A minimal reproducible example would work best here - where from the intial dataframe, you could get the final desired output too

Comment: Sorry, actually the data is sensitive...all I am looking for is `how to assign a different scalar value to each group after pandas and then create a single separate column from that`.